# Drawing Smith Chart from Network Analyzer file

Tags: matlab, network, spectrum-analyzer, smith-chart

I have a file as a .dat format taking from network analyzer. I want to plot Smith chart graph. The file has 3 columns which are frequency, S11(linear value), S11 (ang value) respectively. How can draw my data on Smith Chart by using Matlab, originpro or another apps?

Answer (score 1):

The Smith chart is just a parametric plot of the reflection coefficient (\$S_{11}\$) on the imaginary plane. So convert your magnitude and phase values into real and imaginary components, and plot them on a graph spanning [-1,1] on each axis.

To plot the background of the Smith chart, you just plot curves representing the reflection coefficient for loads with a few values of constant resistance and varying reactance, and for a few values of constant reactance with varying resistance. Choose whatever particular values make the chart look nice.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem (that plotting multiple S11 graphs as one graph) using with **origionpro** tool. fyi